# The exact same view renders correctly from XML but not from the Java code

Tags: java, android, xml, android-bootstrap

I'm trying to render a view that looks good when I statically render it with XML but when I replicate the same structure in Java it does not.

```xml
   <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/trends_table_body"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:background="@drawable/border">
            
            <TableRow android:weightSum="100">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_weight="5"
                    android:background="@drawable/border"
                    android:text="5"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/bootstrap_h4_text_size" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="30"
                    android:background="@drawable/border"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.AwesomeTextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:rotation="135"
                        android:text=""
                        app:bootstrapBrand="danger"
                        app:fontAwesomeIcon="fa_arrow_up" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_weight="25"
                    android:background="@drawable/border"
                    android:text="BTC/USDT"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/bootstrap_h4_text_size" />


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_weight="26"
                    android:background="@drawable/border"
                    android:text="22%"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/bootstrap_h4_text_size" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="14"
                    android:background="@drawable/border"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.BootstrapButton

                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:text="More"
                        app:bootstrapBrand="primary"
                        app:bootstrapSize="sm"
                        app:buttonMode="regular"
                        app:roundedCorners="true"
                        app:showOutline="false" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>
```

Java:

```java
private TableRow createStaticEvent(final EventDto event) {
        // create LayoutParams for image and button's Linear Layouts (elements goes from 0 to 4)
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams wrapContent1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        wrapContent1.weight = 30f;

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams wrapContent4 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        wrapContent4.weight = 14f;

        // container
        TableRow eventView = new TableRow(TrendsActivity.this);
        eventView.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        eventView.setWeightSum(100);

        // Row Index
        TextView rowIndex = new AppCompatTextView(TrendsActivity.this);
        TableRow.LayoutParams rowIndex_lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 5);
        rowIndex.setLayoutParams(rowIndex_lp);
        rowIndex.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        rowIndex.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border);
        rowIndex.setText("1"); // TODO - needs to be dynamically
        rowIndex.setTextSize(R.dimen.bootstrap_h4_text_size);

        // arrow (in LinearLayout - LayoutParams1)
        AwesomeTextView expectedTo = new AwesomeTextView(TrendsActivity.this);
        TableRow.LayoutParams expectedTo_lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        expectedTo.setLayoutParams(expectedTo_lp);
        expectedTo.setRotation(45f); // TODO - needs to be dynamically
        expectedTo.setText("");
        expectedTo.setBootstrapBrand(DefaultBootstrapBrand.SUCCESS);
        expectedTo.setFontAwesomeIcon(FontAwesome.FA_ARROW_UP);

        LinearLayout expectedToContainer = new LinearLayout(TrendsActivity.this);
        expectedToContainer.setLayoutParams(wrapContent1);
        expectedToContainer.addView(expectedTo);

        // asset
        TextView asset = new TextView(TrendsActivity.this);
        TableRow.LayoutParams asset_lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 25f);
        asset.setLayoutParams(asset_lp);
        asset.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border);
        asset.setText("BTC/USDT"); // TODO - needs to be dynamically
        asset.setTextSize(R.dimen.bootstrap_h4_text_size);
        asset.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

        // probability
        TextView probability = new TextView(TrendsActivity.this);
        TableRow.LayoutParams probability_lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 26f);
        probability.setLayoutParams(probability_lp);
        probability.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border);
        probability.setText("10%"); // TODO - needs to be dynamically
        probability.setTextSize(R.dimen.bootstrap_h4_text_size);
        probability.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

        // moreButton
        BootstrapButton moreButton = new BootstrapButton(TrendsActivity.this);
        TableRow.LayoutParams moreButton_lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        moreButton.setLayoutParams(moreButton_lp);
        moreButton.setBootstrapBrand(DefaultBootstrapBrand.PRIMARY);
        moreButton.setBootstrapSize(DefaultBootstrapSize.SM);
        moreButton.setButtonMode(ButtonMode.REGULAR);
        moreButton.setRounded(true);
        moreButton.setShowOutline(false);
        moreButton.setText("More");
        moreButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(TrendsActivity.this, TrendActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("id", "5e9b4f6a48cdb0002ab99f78"); // TODO - needs to be dynamically
                TrendsActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        LinearLayout moreButtonContainer = new LinearLayout(TrendsActivity.this);
        moreButtonContainer.setLayoutParams(wrapContent4);
        moreButtonContainer.addView(moreButton);

        eventView.addView(rowIndex);
        eventView.addView(expectedToContainer);
        eventView.addView(asset);
        eventView.addView(probability);
        eventView.addView(moreButtonContainer);

        return eventView;
    }
```

Layout inspector shows a height of 85 for the XML rendered view:
[XML rendered view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7L1w.png)

Layout inspector shows a height of 0 for the Java rendered view:
[Java rendered view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SJYf.png)

Even if I manually set the height as 85 (`eventView.setMinimumHeight(85);`) it shows an empty view. The elements inside are rendered with height 0.